# Android onKeyUp() not calling properly on some emulators

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, keyboard-events

My name is Bruno.
Unfortunately I am having a problem with key pressing.

**The problem:**
When I press any key from the keyboard and keep it pressed, the function **onKeyUp()** is called
without releasing that key. **The correct behavior is:** when we press a key, the function **onKeyDown()** is called and when that key is released, **onKeyUp()** is called.

I tested some Android emulators and only some of them this problem occurs. I want to use Android Studio Emulator. For example, Bluestacks this problem don't happens. I don't know why this occurs on some emulators.

Here is my code, **MainActivity.java**:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    Log.i("KEYTEST", event.toString());

    return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    Log.i("KEYTEST", event.toString());

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

When I press 'D' key and keep it pressed, then log prints:
[log image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3Cmj.png)

What is happening? There a problem with certain emulators in combination with portuguese keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use onKeyUp and onKeyDown for letters.  Most keyboards don't use them, they send data via the commitText() function of the InputMethodConnection.  That completely bypasses the key up/key down system.  Those are only reliable for physical buttons.  Like the volume buttons, or a hardware keyboard attached via bluetooth.

Comment: Thank you! The problem is with the emulator (that not implement this functionality) or the keyboard?

Comment: @BrunoGonçalves There's a richer API that the software keyboard use instead.  Sending raw key events is rather limiting, and a bit of a pain in the neck.  So most choose not to do it that way.